# How to allow install of non app store or identified developers on MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, security, permission

I'm getting this error trying to install software on MacOS Sierra (10.12.5):

Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the App Store and identified developers.

I'd like to change the settings so that these types of installations are allowed. Similar to what is shown here:

http://www.synergy.com/wordpress_650164087/faqs/if-you-get-the-following-error-trying-to-install-kg-under-os-10-8-your-security-preferences-allow-installation-of-only-apps-from-the-mac-app-store-and-identified-developers/

However, my system doesn't seem to have the Anywhere option (screen shot below). This option is also not available if the Advanced button is selected.

[image]

Comment: You can use the Open Anyway feature. That should install it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From: [How to Allow Apps from Anywhere in macOS Sierra Gatekeeper](http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/27/allow-apps-from-anywhere-macos-gatekeeper/)

> 1. Quit  out of System Preferences
> 2. Open the Terminal app from the /Applications/Utilities/ folder and then enter the following command syntax:
>
>    ```
>    sudo spctl --master-disable
>    ```
> 3. Hit return and authenticate with an admin password
> 4. Relaunch System Preferences and go to “Security & Privacy” and the “General” tab
> 5. You will now see the “Anywhere” option under ‘Allow apps downloaded from:’ Gatekeeper options

Comment: It doesn't help with installing ExifTool.

Comment: Nice! That rocks, it works for Catalina too. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Just right-click (or <kbd>^ ctrl</kbd> click) the `pkg` file in question and choose `Open`. This will let you open the file no matter where it came from. Note that this is different from double-clicking.

You can do this with any application downloaded from the Internet, and macOS will remember that application next time you run it.

From a security standpoint, I prefer doing this over disabling the safeguard systemwide.

Comment: It is still possible - even on the upcoming High Sierra is it possible

Comment: I stand corrected—I thought I remembered reading about that somewhere. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Did you mean "Note that this is different from double-clicking"?

Comment: My brain just wasn't quite there this morning 

Comment: If I have a bunch of executables I need to authorize, is there a way to do this from the Terminal?  I don't want to completely disable GateKeeper, just mimic the functionality of right-clicking and clicking open

Answer (score 3):

To do this without needing admin privileges and without disabling security features:

- Open up terminal
- Type `xattr -c`
- Drag (from finder) the file you wish to open into the terminal window
- Run the command by pressing Enter

`xattr -c` removes the metadata of a file or folder. This removes the developer, date of download and a few other things. It does not effect the contents of the app.

Answer (score 0):

As of macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, right-clicking (or <kbd>^ ctrl</kbd> clicking) .app packages, which are not registered with Apple by an identified developer, and choosing Open won't work, so the only option left is to enable the Anywhere option under Security and Privacy in System Preferences (at least temporarily).

From [How to open apps from unidentified developers on macOS Sierra](https://www.imore.com/how-open-apps-unidentified-developers-mac):

> 1. Close System Preferences on your Mac.
> 2. Open Terminal.
> 3. Type the following command:
>
>    `sudo spctl --master-disable`
> 4. Hit enter on your keyboard.
> 5. Enter your administrator password.
> 6. Hit enter on your keyboard.

This will restore the Anywhere setting and select it by default. To verify you can open System Preferences and select Security & Privacy.

To return to the default and more secure GateKeeper settings, follow the same steps, changing the command to 
`sudo spctl --master-enable`